# Use Xml Tags Multiple times with Template

Tags: xml, xslt

how to make last most date come up on the top using xslt

```
<records>
  <LATEST_TITLE>
    <LATEST_DATE>2013-12-10</LATEST_DATE>
    <TITLE>abc</TITLE>
  </LATEST_TITLE>
  <LATEST_TITLE>
    <LATEST_DATE>2013-12-13</LATEST_DATE>
    <TITLE>def</TITLE>
  </LATEST_TITLE>
  <LATEST_TITLE>
    <LATEST_DATE>2013-12-17</LATEST_DATE>
    <TITLE>ghi</TITLE>
  </LATEST_TITLE>
</records>
```

expected output

```
2013-12-17
abc
def
ghi
```

can we make use of template two times

Comment: How is using templates multiple times related to displaying the most recent date?

Comment: Does the order of the titles matter here? If not, you can sort the records by date, and output the date only if position() = 1.

Comment: Is that definitely the output you expect? That is, you only want to output the most recent date, followed by the title text in their original order? And is it definitely text to be output, not xml?

Comment: yes, that is the only main problem.

Comment: i feel using two template we can achieve this output. first template can we used to display date and the other template can be used to display the title. yes, i need the output in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted two templates matching the same element, you can make use of the mode attribute

```
<xsl:template match="LATEST_TITLE" mode="date">
   <!-- Code here to output the date -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LATEST_TITLE" mode="title">
   <!-- Code here to output the title -->
</xsl:template>
```

And to call them, you would specify the required mode when do apply-templates

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="LATEST_TITLE" mode="date" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="LATEST_TITLE" mode="title" />
```

The only extra work you really have to do is add a xsl:sort to the first apply-templates, to sort by date, and then change the matching template to only output the element in the first position.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LATEST_TITLE" mode="date">
         <xsl:sort select="LATEST_DATE" order="descending" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LATEST_TITLE" mode="title" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="LATEST_TITLE" mode="date">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
         <xsl:value-of select="LATEST_DATE" />
         <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="LATEST_TITLE" mode="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```